# delete row from datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i am trying to delete selected row from data grid, by double click on the row.

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int selected_index = planeList.SelectedIndex;
        string cellValue = GetSelectedCellValue();
        MessageBox.Show(selected_index.ToString());
        if (m.removePlane(cellValue))
        {
           // planeList.Items.Clear();
            planeList.Items.RemoveAt(selected_index);
            planeList.Items.Refresh();

        }
```

xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="planeList" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsReadOnly="True" 
              >
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_DoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Everything works fine until removeAt, at this point I have an exception 'out of range', but the chosen index equals 0 or greater.
Also, an item is selected as null returns.
I really do not know what I'm missing
Thanks.

edit: planeList.Items.Clear(); was on the wrong place. thanks!

Comment: if you clear your items, you can't remove anything

Comment: I guess you mean this `planeList.Items.RemoveAt(selected_index);` throws the exception. This is cause by clearing the list in the line before. _Edit: Do you want to remove one or all selected items? Your title/question differs from the code you've provided us._

Comment: Why are you removing it twice?

Comment: Your edit just fixed the initial problem, but you can run into this exception again. At first you are removing all selected items within the while and after that you removed the item at the previously saved index. For example you: You have 10 items in your list and the last four selected. Now you double click on the index 8 (row 9). You will remove 6-9 and now you want to remove index 8 from a list with indexes [0:5].